# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. getting this error when i am returning File object

Tags: android, flutter

this is my function, and I am getting error when I return File object

```
static Future<File> pickFile() async {
final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
);
if (result == null) {
  throw Exception('No files picked or file picker was canceled');
}
return File(result.paths.first);
```

}

Comment: Please post the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

this is b'coz null safety . you such need to add null check(!) on that variable which to decalare nullable ? .

Comment: I have done that but still getting same problem .